# While loop within Javascript function

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the following basic function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Form_Data(theForm)
{

var t=1;
while (t<=5) {

if (theForm.F[t]FirstName.value == "")
    {
    alert("Please enter Fighter 1's First Name.");
    theForm.F[t]FirstName.focus();
    return (false);
    }
t++;
}

return (true);
}
</script>
```

The script (js validation) fails using this code. If I remove the [t] and replace with a number (1,2,3,4,etc), the validation works on the appropriate fields. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the parentheses in `return` statements are not necessary :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `F[t]FirstName` looks to me like invalid syntax.

Comment: @Matchu - thank you for iterating my question/point. I have errors so something is not right with the code. As I state at the end, if I replace the variable with a number I get my validation. I have over 20 IF statements and up to 16 different 't' values

Comment: @JM4 - Are you replacing the t with a number or are you replacing [t] with a number?  Please post a snippet of the code that works.  We don't know what your object model looks like.

Comment: @tehMick - [t] with a number so the end result would look like: theForm.F3FirstName.value

Comment: @JM4 - Both `F[t]FirstName` and `F[1]FirstName` throw syntax errors in my Javascript console.

Comment: @JM4 - then go with Guffa's answer, but lose the dot.

Comment: @JM4 - It most definitely is the solution to the problem you're describing. If the solution without the dot doesn't work, then there is another issue.

Comment: You might also benefit from using another loop inside the larger loop, if you're really repeating similar logic 20 times. Just a tip to keep yourself sane in the future :)

Comment: @JM4 - It really should work.  Post your latest attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an index as part of a name, you have to put the name together as a string and use as index:

```
theForm['F' + t + 'FirstName']
```

Comment: You don't need both the dot and the brackets.

Comment: @JM4 - I removed the syntax error. Looking at the comments, this *is* the solution to your problem :) Brackets represent accessing a property, not interpolating into a property name.

Comment: @Matchu - no this is not, this solution does not work. I have tried it.

Comment: @JM4 - Yeah. It is. Given the problem you describe, this is the solution. Please include a more complete code sample in the original question, because there *must* be an additional issue.

Comment: @JM4 - Comment spam, sorry. Here is the a link to what I assume to be the general structure of your document. This fix works: http://jsbin.com/ubazi3/edit (though I note that each error alerts "Fighter 1" instead of "Fighter {t}")

Comment: @Matchu - just value is added - I asumed you mean remove both dots so it was theForm['F' + t + 'FirstName']value - all resolved! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any way in the alert to also reflect the t value instead of the number 1?

Comment: @JM4 - `alert("Please enter Fighter " + t + "'s First Name.");`

Comment: @JM4 - Glad to help :P Just to give that answer a bit of explanation... If I have an object with the property `foo`, I can get to it with the easier syntax of `obj.foo`, or I can use `obj[foo]`. They are completely interchangable. You'll use the first more often, but the second allows you to include some more Javascript code inside the brackets, whereas the first will only take a straight-up, hard-coded property name. Hope that makes things a tad clearer :)

Comment: @Matchu: Just a small correction: it's `obj['foo']`, not `obj[foo]`. :)